# Why should I use velocity equations instead of position ones in Projectile Motion

Tags: c++, motion, projectile

I've got a question, I've seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2481362), that velocity equations are better than position ones in Projectile Motion. Can someone explain me please, why should I do that?

Why I am asking about that? I was trying to simulate Horizontal, Vertical and Projectile motion, and now, when I've made almost everything, I've started to wondering, how to add Air-Resistance, so it would look more realistic. 
Almost all of solutions, which I've seen are using velocity equations right here.
I was wondering if I can add Air-Resistance based on position equations, or it's a must to use velocity equations right here.

I've made so far this code, and it works good as well.

```
else if (whichThrow == 3) {
    while (t < totalTime) {
        tempX = velocity[0] * t;
        tempY = velocity[1] * t - (acceleration / 2)*t*t;
        t += step;
        coords.push_back(make_pair(tempX, tempY));
        printf("[%f][%f]\n", tempX, tempY);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where does that "thread" say that?

Comment: In Benny Jobigan answer

Comment: So in a non-accepted answer with plenty of comments explaining that the accepted answer is better, and pointing out flaws in the answer?

Comment: IMO you shouldn't. Stick to your code which looks more or less OK to me.

Comment: To use velocity equations and to solve the ODE numerically, instead of just using direct equations for position makes sense only if your velocity equations are too complicated to be solved analytically.

Comment: @MaciejWroński You should probably explain us a bit more about the context where you want to use the projectile motion. Is it a game? Is it a physics simulation etc.? The answer may depend on it.

Comment: Thanks for answers. Sorry yeah I should. I was trying to simulate Horizontal, Vertical and Projectile motion, and now, when I've made almost everything, I've started to wondering, how to add Air-Resistance right here, so it would look more realistic.  Almost all of solutions, which I've seen are using velocity equations right here. I was wondering if I can add Air-Resistance based on position equations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we simulating motion, there would be many external forces apply on the object such as gravity, collision, wind, etc. It would be more convenient to make it in velocity because it will be interchangeable between acceleration and position.

Since you mentioned about the drag force of the air which is defined as [<sup>[Wikipedia]</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_equation):

[image: drag_force]

where :

- F is the drag force, which is by definition the force component in the direction of the flow velocity,
- [image: eqn] is the mass density of the fluid,[1]
- [image: eqn] is the flow velocity relative to the object,
- [image: eqn] is the reference area, and
- [image: eqn] is the drag coefficien,

  we know that the motion is velocity-dependent. To be more clear, you could visit [this](http://natureofcode.com/book/chapter-2-forces/).

Comment: Thanks for answer! That's all I needed. Have a nice day